# Sending mails in Java script?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a function to send an email when the user clicks on "submit".

Any ideas how to do so?

Lets say I have a

```
<script>
function mail()
{

    var players = document.getElementById('players').value;
    var slots = document.getElementById('slots').value;

}
</script>
```

and I want to generate an mail with those three vars.

Thanks all :)!

Comment: Is PHP available to you? Then you could just send an AJAX request to a PHP file that handles the mailing for you.

Comment: There are only *two* variables. Also, you'd need to submit the details to a server-side script to send the email, JavaScript has no capacity to send email independently.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"You may need to post the details to a server which would mail or you can use the mailto function to invoke default mail client on the client's computer like

variable1:
variable2:

"

This answer above will not work for people who do not have a mail client installed on their os.  the mailto feature in html will open up the users  "outlook" type program to send the mail.

Answer (score 4):

You can't send emails from (client-side) JavaScript alone. What you can do is write a *server-side* program that takes inputs (maybe as a POST or XHR request), creates an email out of it and sends it.

Comment: do you have any exmpls ? Thanks ! :)

Comment: @Alon M I'm afraid it's more than could be reasonable covered in a single example, and it totally depends on what server-side language and environment you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to post the details to a server which would mail or you can use the mailto function to invoke default mail client on the client's computer like

```
<form action="mailto:sample@stackoverflow.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" >
variable1:<input type="text" name="v1">
variable2:<input type="text" name="v2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use it in combination of a server side language and javascript.  You can use javascript to write the "interface" to the mail function. But you will need to look into php or another language.

A php example of this is

You can find more details on the manual here http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php

pinehead.tv fighting for smarter newbies

Comment: Then you can call the mailer in javascript with something like "location.href='mymailer.php?player='+escape(mydata)+'&data='+escape(otherdata);"